# WordPress query - exclude meta values that are repeating

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, unique

I have a custom meta filed called country, and I want to get the values from the meta key and add them into a dropdown, but the problem I'm having is that I don't need to display all of the meta values(because some of them are repeating) only unique ones.

For **example** I'm displaying: Italy Germany Italy Italy USA and I would like to only display: Italy Germany USA

```
$query = new WP_Query(
            array(               
                'meta_key' => 'country',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order'=> 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
            )               
         );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while( $query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();
        $metas = get_post_custom($post->ID);
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $metas['country'][0]; ?>">
        <?php echo $metas['country'][0]; ?>
    </option>

<?php

    }//while
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
}//if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use a custom query to get all the distinct values of the meta_key 'countries' from the database.

```
<?php
global $wpdb; 

$countries = $wpdb->get_results( 
   "SELECT DISTINCT(meta_value) 
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'country'
    ORDER BY meta_value"
);

if($countries){ 

    echo '<select name="countries">';

    foreach ( $countries as $country ) {
    echo '<option value="' .$country->meta_value .'">';
        echo $country->meta_value;
        echo '</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';

} 

?>
```